# X after X construction?

Tags: terminology, x-bar-theory

We were given some data and the questions below. I don't need someone to tell me the answer, I just need someone to help explain what X after X construction is. It makes NO sense to me!

Major questions: what is the structure of the construction itself? What type of phrase is it, what’s its head? Jackendoff presents one analysis where the first N is the head, and the rest is its complement. He ultimately favors an analysis where this is a strange sort of PP, though, with the P as its head. You should present possible trees of each of these types and choose one.

Comment: It's another kind of technical term that you're sposta already understand because it's so intuitive and we all have the same universal grammar. However, it's just one brand of syntax, and you'll never hear about any other brands from this teacher.

Comment: I have not read Jackendoff's analysis of the "X after X" construction, but I can provide a couple of insights. The construction is an adjunct, not an argmument. It is therefore an optional constituent in the clause where it appears, e.g. "Fred said it (time after time)". As an adjunct, the construction is unusual, since most phrasal adjuncts in English are headed by a preposition, whereas the "X after X" construction appears to be headed by a noun (the first X). In the scheme of things, the X after X construction is problematic because it does not fit neatly into any established category.

Comment: So it is now its own established category. Into which it fits neatly.

Comment: Yes, which is what a Construction Grammar approach would claim. My guess is that Jackendoff agrees with this much.